# Half of a Cohen real

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I recently heard from a friend that Zapletal gave a talk at Toronoto where he constructed a proper forcing which adds a real which infinitely often equals every ground model real but doesn't add a Cohen real thereby answering the "Half of a Cohen real" problem (Arnie's problem 5.7 and Fremlin's problem DQ). I could not get the details from my friend and I cannot find a write-up on Zapletal's webpage.

Can someone describe his forcing?

Comment: http://www.fields.utoronto.ca/programs/scientific/12-13/forcing/cardinals/Zapletal_Jindrich.pdf

Comment: Thanks. So now I need a reference to a construction of a compact infinite dimensional metric space all of whose closed subspaces are either zero or infinite dimensional.

Comment: I just noticed the following write up of Zapletal: http://people.clas.ufl.edu/zapletal/files/fremlin2.pdf